# Listview search can't find data in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a name search for characters from the SW Api, but the search doesn't work for some reason, can someone please tell me where the error is? Maybe the problem is in the List itself?

```
class _SWMainState extends State<SWMain> {
  Icon customIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
  static Text titleText = Text("Star Wars API");
  Widget customSearchBar = titleText;
  var search = List<Character>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: customSearchBar,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: customIcon,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (this.customIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                      this.customIcon = Icon(Icons.cancel);
                      this.customSearchBar = TextField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: "Search character"),
                        onChanged: (text) {
                          text = text.toLowerCase();
                          search = search.where((search) {
                            var charTitle = search.name.toLowerCase();
                            return charTitle.contains(text);
                          }).toList();
                        },
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      );
                    } else {
                      this.customIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
                      this.customSearchBar = titleText;
                    }
                  });
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator"

Answer (score 0):

First off, every search implementation in flutter requires a Search Delegate that will be responsible for rendering the Search Results Widget.

In this case you can create a delegate class like so:

```
class CustomSearchItemsDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = 'My Query coming from Variable';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    if (query.length == 0) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Please enter an appropriate search field...",
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
       //Render the Search Results Widget here if any exist
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Column();
  }
}
```

Then in your class Widget that is responsible for invoking search, add this:

```
await showSearch(
        query: "My Search Query...", context: context, delegate: CustomSearchItemsDelegate());
```

So your final State's component class will be:

```
class _SWMainState extends State<SWMain> {
  Icon customIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
  static Text titleText = Text("Star Wars API");
  Widget customSearchBar = titleText;
  var search = List<Character>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: customSearchBar,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: customIcon,
                onPressed: () async {
                     await showSearch(query: "My Search Query...", context:context, delegate: CustomSearchItemsDelegate()); //Let the search delegate manage the UI 
                  });
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then just let the **CustomSearchItemsDelegate** manage the UI and its own state management